# How to place buttons close to each other on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have searched all over the internet and even here, but I was not able to get an answer to this.

I am a new iphone developer and this is my first app. My iPhone app's designer has placed a couple of buttons very close to each other, as a result when I am clicking on one button, the lower button is getting clicked.

I am not sure if this is a fault of design or development?

Any guidance will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Nirali

Comment: more details please....

Comment: Yes, more details please. You don't say whether you're certain the button's frames are non-overlapping, and you don't say whether you're certain the correct action handlers are attached to each button. Problems with either one could cause the wrong code to execute, and would have nothing to do with touch-point-detection accuracy because of big fingers on small buttons.

Comment: [How to add several UIBarButtonItems to a NavigationBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431435/how-to-add-several-uibarbuttonitems-to-a-navigationbar/8431954#8431954) This may help you.

Comment: @user2664358  You should be careful that buttons frame should not overLap each other and should have minimum 10 PXl space between two buttons. It will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons are not meant to be close together and should be at least 10 points away from each other or the buttons size should be at least 44x44 points in order to be easily pushed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked :(id)sender
{
    UIButton* clickedBtn = (UIButton*) sender;
    int buttonTAg = clickedBtn.tag;

        if(buttonTAg == 1)
        {
    
           // first button action
    
              return;
        }
        else if(buttonTAg == 2)
        {
    
          // second button action
    
             return;
        }
        else if(buttonTAg == 3)
        {
    
          // third button action
    
             return;
        }

       else if(buttonTAg == 4)
       {
    
         // fourth button action
    
            return;
       }


}
```

---

- List item

  ### [image: button properties]

disabling autoresizing of width and height
[image: background and tag]

for each button give tag in the order 1 , 2 3, ...